Hyperlink result in excel from MySQL query
I have created a report for a client and the output results are in Excel.
This is the code used
concat('https://client.site.com/ats/resume_dashboard.php?candidate_id=',
       `Applicant Details`.`Candidate ID`)

How do I make the link in the result set a hyperlink?
This is the code used
concat( 'https://client.site.com/ats/resume_dashboard.php?candidate_id=', `Applicant Details`.`Candidate ID` )

expected result is when they click on the link to take them to the actual candidate dashboard

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hyperlink-function-333c7ce6-c5ae-4164-9c47-7de9b76f577f
